# construction of a Unitary matrix from another one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a  $4 \times4$ matrix with complex entries with columns and rows are mutually orthogonal and row/column vectors have norm $\sqrt{2}$ where the the rows and columns are indexed by $(i,j)$, $i,j=1,2$ such that if you put any column/row of $A$ into a $2 \times 2$ matrix will be unitary. From $A$ I want to construct another matrix $B$ which has the following property.Columns /rows are mutually orthogonal and each has norm $\sqrt{2}$ and if we take any two columns indexed by (-,j). From these take the rows indexed by (i,-). The resultant $2 \times 2$ matrix should be unitary. How can we get $B$ from $A$? Please help me. By which matrix we should apply to $A$ to get $B$?
That is explicitely I have the following data.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a^{11}_{11} & a^{11}_{12} & a^{11}_{21} &   a^{11}_{22} \\
    a^{12}_{11} & a^{12}_{12} & a^{12}_{21} &   a^{12}_{22} \\
    a^{21}_{11} & a^{21}_{12} & a^{21}_{21} &   a^{21}_{22} \\
   a^{22}_{11} & a^{22}_{12} & a^{22}_{21} &   a^{22}_{22}  
\end{bmatrix}
$
and I have the following matrices are unitary.

$C_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{11} & a^{21}_{11}\\
 a^{12}_{11} & a^{22}_{11}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{12} & a^{21}_{12}\\
 a^{12}_{12} & a^{22}_{12}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{21}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{21} & a^{21}_{21}\\
 a^{12}_{21} & a^{22}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$C_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a^{11}_{22} & a^{21}_{22}\\
 a^{12}_{22} & a^{22}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$

I need to construct a $B$ from $A$ having the following property.
If $B=\begin{bmatrix}
    b^{11}_{11} & b^{11}_{12} & b^{11}_{21} &   b^{11}_{22} \\
    b^{12}_{11} & b^{12}_{12} & b^{12}_{21} &   b^{12}_{22} \\
    b^{21}_{11} & b^{21}_{12} & b^{21}_{21} &   b^{21}_{22} \\
   b^{22}_{11} & b^{22}_{12} & b^{22}_{21} &   b^{22}_{22}  
\end{bmatrix}
$ Then $B$ should satisfy the following conditions.

1. $B$ should have mutually orthogonal rows and columns with norm being $\sqrt{2}$
2. The following matrices formed from $B$ are unitary.

$D_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{11}_{11} & b^{11}_{21}\\
 b^{12}_{11} & b^{12}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{11}_{12} & b^{11}_{22}\\
 b^{12}_{12} & b^{12}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{21}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{21}_{11} & b^{21}_{21}\\
 b^{22}_{11} & b^{22}_{21}
 \end{bmatrix}$,

$D_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}
 b^{21}_{12} & b^{21}_{22}\\
 b^{22}_{12} & b^{22}_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}$
Is there any way to construct $B$ using $A$?

Comment: @user1551 I have edited the question for the clarification

Comment: Such a $B$ cannot exist. If we swap the second and the third columns of $B$ and partition the resultant matrix as $C=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}$, then $C,X,Y,Z,W$ are all unitary matrices. Yet this is impossible, as the diagonal block of $CC^\ast$ is $XX^\ast+YY^\ast=2I_2$.

Comment: How are you concluding that $C$ is unitary? This $C$ is not the $A$ said earlier. My question is, I have an $A$ with the stated properties. Can I construct somehow such a $B$? If $A$ has the special property that $Y=Z$ then we can take $B$ to be $A$ itself. But if $Y \neq Z$ I am stuck. By multiplying with some matrix to $A$ will we get?

Comment: If $B$ is unitary, $BP$ is also unitary for every permutation matrix $P$. In particular, if you swap any two columns of a unitary matrix $B$, the resulting matrix must be unitary too. That was why I said $C$ is unitary.

Comment: @ user1551  I agree with you that such a $B$ cannot exist. Let me relax the conditions. Now $A$ is not necessarily unitary. But $A$ has mutually orthogonal rows and columns and each row/column has norm $\sqrt{2}$. Also the sub matrices of $A$ constructed as above are unitary.  Now I need a $B$ with mutually orthogonal rows and columns with each column/row has norm  $\sqrt{2}$ and the sub matrices as above are unitary. In this case is it possible?

Comment: I have edited the hypothesis

Comment: X-post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/271857/91764